# Filter array based on an array of index

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

First I apologize if it's a duplicate (I searched but did not find this simple example...), but I want to select elements of `arr1` based on the index in `arr2`:

```
arr1 = [33,66,77,8,99]
arr2 = [2,0,3]
```

I am using `underscore.js` but the `0` index is not retrieved (seems to be considered as `false`):

```
res = _.filter(arr1, function(value, index){
    if(_.contains(arr2, index)){
        return index;
    }
});
```

Which returns:

```
# [77, 8]
```

How could I fix this, and is there a simpler way to filter using an array of indexes? I am expecting the following result:

```
# [77, 33, 8]
```

Comment: change your if statement to if(_.contains(arr2, index) >= 0)

Comment: @82Tuskers I think you are confusing `_.contains` with `indexOf`.

Comment: absolutely right ! @joews thanks for pointing that out ...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `_.map` on `arr2`, like this

```
console.log(_.map(arr2, function (item) {
  return arr1[item];
}));
// [ 77, 33, 8 ]
```

Here, we iterate the indexes and fetching the corresponding values from `arr1` and creating a new array.

---

Equivalent to the above, but perhaps a bit more advanced, is to use `_.propertyOf` instead of the anonymous function:

```
console.log(_.map(arr2, _.propertyOf(arr1)));
// [ 77, 33, 8 ]
```

---

If your environment supports ECMA Script 6's Arrow functions, then you can also do

```
console.log(_.map(arr2, (item) => arr1[item]));
// [ 77, 33, 8 ]
```

---

Moreover, you can use the native `Array.protoype.map` itself, if your target environment supports them, like this

```
console.log(arr2.map((item) => arr1[item]));
// [ 77, 33, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 12):

for me the best way to do this is with **filter**.

```
let z=[10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]

let x=[0,3,7]

z.filter((el,i)=>x.some(j => i === j))
//result
[10, 13, 17]
```

Comment: While correct, the running time of this solution scales with both the length of `z` and the length of `x`. So if both are long, this is going to take very long.

Answer (score 4):

One can use the `filter` method on the array that one wants to subset. The [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) iterates over the array and returns a new one consisting of the items that pass the test. The test is a callback function, in the example below an anonymous arrow function, that accepts required `currentValue` and optional `index` parameters. In the example below I used `_` as the first parameter since it is not utilized and that way the linter does not highlight it as unused :).
Within the callback function the [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method of array is used on the array that we use as the source of indices to check whether the current index of the `arr1` is part of the desired indices.

```js
let arr1 = [33, 66, 77, 8, 99];
let arr2 = [2, 0, 3];
let output = arr1.filter((_, index) => arr2.includes(index));
console.log("output", output);
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28340433)

Comment: @Cannicide, please run the code snippet above

Comment: My review was automatically converted into a comment. More accurately, what I meant is that this answer does not provide a *full* answer to the question. Yes, your code works, but code-only answers are generally considered low quality and incomplete. Explain what your code does, how it works, what mistake the OP made in their attempt (if relevant), etc. Otherwise, others struggling to find an answer to this question will not be able to improve their understanding of both their problem and its solution.

Comment: @Cannicide, excellent point and I am sorry for not adhering to SO standards. I hope my modifications make the answer more helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `index`, so in your case `0` treated as `false`. So you need to return `true` instead

```
res = _.filter(arr1, function(value, index){
    if(_.contains(arr2, index)){
        return true;
    }
});
```

or just return `_.contains()`

```
res = _.filter(arr1, function(value, index){
   return _.contains(arr2, index);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`_.contains` returns a boolean. You should return that from the `filter` predicate, rather than the index because `0` is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

```
res = _.filter(arr1, function(value, index)) {
  return _.contains(arr2, index);
});
```

As an aside, JavaScript arrays have a native `filter` method so you could use:

```
res = arr1.filter(function(value, index)) {
  return _.contains(arr2, index);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it better to iterate through indices array as main loop?

```
var arr1 = [33,66,77,8,99]
var arr2 = [2,0,3] 
var result = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr2.length; i++) {
   var index = arr2[i];
   result.push(arr1[index]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I can't stand loops :) Too many lines and playing with indexes is not a good idea!