# Filter array by array of indexes

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a first array of values and a second array of indexes.  I would like to filter the first array and return only values that have indexes in the second array.

So, given:

```
arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376]
arr2 = [0,2]
```

I would like to return:

```
output = [4775453877338112, 6605041225957376]
```

Thanks.  For bonus points, why doesn't the following work?

`var output = arr1.filter( (item) => arr1.indexOf(item) in arr2 === true )`

Apologies if this simple question is a duplicate of this: [Filter array based on an array of index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33211799/filter-array-based-on-an-array-of-index), but the underscore is throwing me off.

Comment: ```var output = arr1.filter( (item) => arr2.indexOf(arr1.indexOf(item)) >= 0 )``` will work

**Seems most Effective**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> For bonus points, why doesn't the following work?

Because you are checking **if the *index* is present in `arr2`, not the item itself**.

Just simply use a `map`

```
var output = arr2.map( s => arr1[s] );
```

**Demo**

```js
var arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376];
var arr2 = [0,2];
var output = arr2.map( s => arr1[s] );
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Ah, the index, not the integer representing the index...  Explains the weird results I was seeing.  Thank you

Comment: If it's helpful to anyone, `.map()` accepts a second argument for the context of the callback, so the solution could be rewritten like this: `var output = arr2.map(function (s) { return this[s]; }, arr1);` if you want to define a reusable function rather than an anonymous function expression.

Answer (score 4):

`var output = arr1.filter( (item) => arr1.indexOf(item) in arr2 === true )` indexOf returns index of element not a boolean. You could use new `Array.prototype.includes` or test for value to be -1

Also if order is the same you could loop over index array instead.

```js
const arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376]
const arr2 = [0,2]

const output = arr2.map(i => arr1[i])

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 3):

A simple loop might be all you need:

```
arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376];
arr2 = [0,2];
arr3 = [];

for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    arr3.push(arr1[arr2[i]]);
}
```

Result:

```
Array [ 4775453877338112, 6605041225957376 ]
```

Comment: well. guess we had the same intention

Comment: Sure, its the most simple and intentional approach ^^

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution without using an extra empty array and without nesting of the for loop. Also works in O(n) rather than O(n^2) suggested by some people here.

```
var arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376];
var arr2 = [0,2];

var result = arr2.map(i => arr1[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your task is easier when writing a readable code instead of complex code:

```js
var arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376];
var arr2 = [0,2];
var output = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
  output.push(arr1[ arr2[i] ]);
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
`

```js
let arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376]
let arr2 = [0,2]

let result = arr1.filter(i => arr2.includes(arr1.indexOf(i)))
console.log(result);
```

`

Comment: I like it :D (nice answer there)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
  $("document").ready(function(){
    arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376]
arr2 = [0,2]
$.each( arr2, function( key, value ) {
  alert( arr1[value]);
});
    
  })
</script>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: having to use a whole libary for that task might be a little bit overload

Answer (score 0):

Without using lodash this is a way to solve it. Do not use arr.forEach, it is slower than for.

```
const arr1 = [4775453877338112, 5901353784180736, 6605041225957376]
const arr2 = [0,2]
const finalArray = [];
let j = 0;
for (let i = 0, len = arr1.length; i < len; i++) {
  if(i==arr2[j]) {
    j++;
    finalArray.push(arr1[i]);
  }
}
```

Comment: You are overcomplicating it, just loop over the array with the requested indizies ^^

Answer (score 0):

Modify the output variable as follows:

```
var output = arr1.filter((item) => arr2.includes(arr1.indexOf(item)));
```

Answer (score -1):

To be more specific irrespective of type of value, use reflection concept.

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
.
.
.

.

.
int[] arr1 = {1, 3, 7};
int[] arr2 = {0,2};

for (var i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) { 
Object o=Array.get(arr1,  arr2[i]);

System.out.println(o);

}

Output :
1
7

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites.

Comment: This question is for JavaScript, not Java.